# quit qemu ... inside screen inside tmux

Tags: tmux, gnu-screen, qemu

I used too many levels of indirection and now I can't get out.

- I used Tmux from my jump host to get into the dev host.
- Then I used screen to keep track of what I'm doing on the dev host.
- Finally I started a program using Qemu (`--nographic`).

Normally I would quit Qemu using the keys `C-a x`, but:

- I've also bound `C-a` to be my escape for Tmux and Screen.
- Typing `C-a x` and Tmux asks if I want to close the window.
- Typing `C-a C-a x` logs me out of Screen.
- Typing `C-a C-a C-a x` and again Tmux asks if I want to close the window.

How do I send `C-a x` to the triple-nested Qemu?

Comment: For screen to send `C-a` you need to type `C-a a`, so try `C-a C-a a x`

Comment: I knew about `C-a a` to go to the beginning of a line, but I didn't realize it actually meant: "send a literal `C-a` to the application".  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even today, I'm still stuck with this problem. Finally I find that you can use `send-keys` command of tmux to bypass `C-a` binding.

1. Switch foucs to the panes running **qemu**. `C-a` + `o` in my configuration.
2. Press `c-a` which is your escape. Then press `:` to tmux's command mode.
3. Type `send-keys C-a x`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).